# Does the term Genisys have any in-universe meaning?

Tags: the-terminator-series, terminator-genisys

The title of the movie *Terminator: Genisys* is obviously using some made-up, fanciful spelling of the word "genesis". Out-of-universe I assume this is just to make it more trademark-able / license-able.

But is there any meaning behind the word from within the story? Is it ever used, and if so, does anyone explain why they choose to spell it so badly?

Comment: Just a clarification for those seeking to answer - you're aware the "sys" part comes from "system", yes?

Comment: I had assumed that, but then what is "geni"? Why not "Genesys", like every English speaking user of this site wants to spell it? :\

Comment: Wake up people: Linda Hamilton [has an identical twin sister](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0000157/bio), or, to put it another way, a genetically-identical sister. Shorten that, and you get “gene-sis”. Simple!

Comment: @DavidS is that something explained in the new movie?

Comment: @phantom42 someone doesn't like your question very much, it already got a -2. :\

Comment: buncha savages around here.

Comment: They didn't need to modify the spelling to make it trademark-able. That's not how trademarks work. It's clearly a reference to the birth of Skynet while modifying the spelling to make it sounds like a software platform.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

## Genisys = Genius + System

Cyberdyne Systems' *Genisys* is the first computer operating **system** intended for mass use whose design incorporates artificial intelligence research — in order words, this operating system is **smart**.

This isn't explained in the film as directly as the word equation above, but it is heavily implied.

In-universe, it has the effect of being snazzy and fanciful, as you say, for product-selling purposes.  As a homonym of "genesis",

> it also represents Skynet's new path to existence.

Out-of-universe, it represents the birth of new story timelines, meaning more opportunities to create sequels that pale in comparison to *T2*.

Comment: Good theory, but is there any in-universe proof to explain this? Behind the scenes, interviews etc?

Comment: @Stark07 : Nope.  I searched thoroughly.  But as I said, it's heavily implied.  In particular, the character Danny Dyson of Cyberdyne makes comments that hint at this.  Once I have access to a script, I'll insert that.

Comment: -Thank you. I read somewhere that Genisys was meant to be an allusion to SYS- as in system, and genesis- as in birth/beginnning...

Comment: @Stark07 : I agree.  It is definitely supposed to sound like "genesis".  If that were all, then they could have written it "genesys".  I believe the reason for the "i" is the explanation in my answer, and so there are really three words here: genius, system, and genesis. :-)

Comment: Yeah.. that does make a lot of sense.. That's what I thought as well...

Comment: The aesthetics of the word/letterforms have to be taken into account when devising branding. And "genisys" simply looks better than "genesys" (which could also be mispronounced as gene-sys). So, out of universe, that's probably the reason it's spelled with an "i" instead of the second "e."

Comment: @Lèsemajesté : I agree.  (In answering, I took the question to be in-universe, and so I mainly commented on that aspect.)

Answer (score -5):

It stands for 
"General Identification System" 
Also "Genisys" as in the first or new beginning or new age.
It's the beginning of the mark referred to in the book of Revelation of the Bible, a one world tracking system.

Comment: It sounds likely, but do you have anything to back this up?